# UIGraphicsBeginImageContext shadow output is not same as SwiftUI view shadow modifier

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, shadow, uigraphicscontext

I want to fit an image over another image with shadow effect. At first, I build the swiftUI view as follows, then trying to get the same output using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext. But unfortunately, found issue here: the shadow blur  in output image isn't same as the view. I am looking for getting the appropriate solution.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var imageRect : CGRect = .zero
    
    @State private var shadowBlur = 40.0
    @State private var shadowX = 100.0
    @State private var shadowY = 100.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader(content: { geometry in
                ZStack {
                    Image("background")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .overlay {
                            Image("foreground")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .shadow(color: Color.red, radius: CGFloat(shadowBlur), x: shadowX, y: shadowY)
                        }
                        .clipped()
                        .background(GeometryGetter(rect: $imageRect))
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
            })
            
            Button("Click") {
                let fgImage = UIImage(named: "foreground")!
                let bgImage = UIImage(named: "background")!
                
                let scale = bgImage.size.width / imageRect.width
                let fgFrame = fgImage.size.scaleSizeToFit(in: bgImage.size)
                let fggImage = fgImage.resize(targetSize: fgFrame)
                
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bgImage.size)
                bgImage.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)
                let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
                context?.setShadow(offset: CGSize(width: shadowX * scale, height: shadowY * scale), blur: shadowBlur * scale, color: UIColor.red.cgColor)
                let imageDrawPoint = CGPoint(x: bgImage.size.width/2.0 - fggImage.size.width / 2.0, y: bgImage.size.height/2.0 - fggImage.size.height / 2.0)
                fggImage.draw(at: imageDrawPoint)
                
                let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                print("SUCCESS")
                
            }
        }
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    func resize(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let image = self.toCIImage()
        let scaleX = targetSize.width / image.extent.size.width
        let scaleY = targetSize.height / image.extent.size.height
        let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleX, y: scaleY)
        let scaledImage = image.transformed(by: scaleTransform)
        return scaledImage.toUIImage()
    }
}

extension CGSize {
    func scaleSizeToFit(in canvas: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let widthScale = canvas.width / self.width
        let heightScale = canvas.height / self.height
        let scale = min(widthScale, heightScale)
        let scaledSize = CGSize(width: self.width * scale, height: self.height * scale)
        return scaledSize
    }
}

struct GeometryGetter: View {
    @Binding var rect: CGRect

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { (g) -> Path in
            print("width: \(g.size.width), height: \(g.size.height)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.rect = g.frame(in: .global)
            }
            return Path()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Difficult to offer help, because you haven't shown us `GeometryGetter(rect: $imageRect)` / `fgImage.size.scaleSizeToFit(in: bgImage.size)` / `fgImage.resize(targetSize: fgFrame)` ... provide enough code so we can run it and see the output (review [mre]).

Comment: Thank you for your response, and I apologize for not providing detailed information earlier. The variable imageRect is evaluated through the GeometryGetter and represents the frame size of the backgroundImage in the UI. The scaleSizeToFit() function returns the required frame size to ensure a proper fit within the designated frame. Additionally, the resize() function is responsible for resizing the image to the target size. The functions have now been attached, @DonMag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to automatic image scaling, this might not give you **exactly** what you see on screen, but it will be much closer...

You need to set the shadow blur value to match the screen scale factor, so change:

```
context?.setShadow(offset: CGSize(width: shadowX * scale, height: shadowY * scale),
                   blur: shadowBlur * scale,
                   color: UIColor.red.cgColor)
```

to:

```
context?.setShadow(offset: CGSize(width: shadowX * scale, height: shadowY * scale),
                   blur: shadowBlur * scale * UIScreen.main.scale,
                   color: UIColor.red.cgColor)
```

Another option would be to render the view itself (the `ZStack`) to a `UIImage` -- searching for `How to convert a SwiftUI view to a UIImage` comes up with lots of examples.